# Find text in string & set a date

Tags: vba, outlook

I created a script to create a task from email:

My code is this:

```
Sub MakeTaskFromMail2(MyMail As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim strID As String
    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objTask As Outlook.TaskItem
    strID = MyMail.EntryID
    Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olMail = olNS.GetItemFromID(strID)
    Set objTask = Application.CreateItem(olTaskItem)

'    Adjust Subject to remove School:
    Dim sInput As String
    Dim sOutput As String
    sInput = olMail.subject
    sOutput = Mid(sInput, InStr(sInput, "School:") + 8)

'    Get the due date from the body
'    Dim dInput As String
'    Dim dOutput As String
'    dInput = olMail.Body
'    dOutput = Mid(dInput, InStr(dInput, "Due:") + 10)

'    Set the task
    With objTask
        .subject = sOutput
        .DueDate = olMail.SentOn
'        .DueDate = dOutput
        .Body = olMail.Body
    End With
    Call CopyAttachments(olMail, objTask)
    objTask.Save
    Set objTask = Nothing
    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
End Sub
```

All the commented parts are things I added to try and get the Due Date from inside the body of the email.

The body of the email looks something like this:

```
Ticket ID: 3479
Ticket Title: display is now Green and pixelated

Room: 110
Priority: Medium
Due: 2013-12-11
```

How can I find the Due Date inside the body and set it as the Due Date of the task?

Comment: I fixed the issue why it won't run and have edited my question appropriately; it was a security setting with macros.  Restarted Outlook, signed my macro and it runs fine now again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (UNTESTED)

```
'
'~~> Rest of your code
'

Dim strData() As String, tmpString As String
Dim dOutput As Date
Dim tmpAr
Dim i As Long

dInput = olMail.Body
strData() = Split(dInput, vbCrLf)

For i = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)
    If InStr(1, strData(i), "Due:", vbTextCompare) Then
        tmpAr = Split(strData(i), "Due:")
        tmpString = Left(Trim(tmpAr(1)), 10)
        dOutput = DateValue(tmpString)
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

If dOutput = "" Then
    MsgBox "Date not Found"

    Exit Sub
End If

With objTask
    .Subject = sOutput
    .DueDate = olMail.SentOn
    .DueDate = dOutput
    .Body = olMail.Body
End With

'
'~~> Rest of your code
'
```

Comment: I'm not getting any errors - but I'm also not getting the proper date set.  When I added your code the script did not run.